# Importing UMD format third-party library into Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup, umd

I'm using this svelte template to create my app - `degit sveltejs/template svelte-app`.

I have to import a third-party library which is in UMD format and needs HTTP, HTTPS, querystring etc. Anyways, I modify my `package.json` to include this library and import it in `App.svelte` using the syntax below:

```
import { functionname } from 'mythirdpartylibrary/filenamewithoutexternsion';
```

While running `npm run dev`, I get the following warnings in the terminal and I'm unable to use functions defined in the third party JS file:

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
https-proxy-agent (imported by  https-proxy-agent?commonjs-external)
url (imported by  url?commonjs-external)
http (imported by  http?commonjs-external)
querystring (imported by  querystring?commonjs-external)
https (imported by  https?commonjs-external)
(!) Missing global variable names
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules

url (guessing 'require$$0')
http (guessing 'require$$1')
https (guessing 'require$$2')
https-proxy-agent (guessing 'require$$4')
```

And get the error below in the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require$$0 is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:481
```

Here's the code pen that contains the minified node_module javascript file for the imported library - https://codepen.io/leenashah/pen/WNoQeXb

Comment: What is the import statement you’re trying to run? It would be helpful if you included the package name and thing you’re trying to import.

Comment: Could you post your `rollup.config.js` file?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I switched to using webpack for svelte instead of rollup and was able to resolve my issue. I had to add the below to webpack.config.js to get it working   node: {
    child_process: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    crypto: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  },

Comment: @geoff-rich Here's the code pen that contains the minified node_module javascript file for the imported library - https://codepen.io/leenashah/pen/WNoQeXb

Comment: This library file contains code like require('url'), require('http'), require('https'), require('querystring') which is not really needed by our application. So what is the workaround if we need other functions in the library but not the specified require code. I'm guessing the require statements are causing the problem in rollup. Sorry I am not familiar at all with rollup or the library format. Like i mentioned I had to add  node: { child_process: 'empty', fs: 'empty', crypto: 'empty', net: 'empty', tls: 'empty', } to webpack to get it working. Is there an equivalent in rollup ?